# Fastest way to convert a binary file to SQLite database

Tags: database, performance

I've some binary files and I'm looking for a way to convert each of those files to a SQLite database. I've already tried C# but the performance is too slow. I'm seeking an advice on how and what programming language should be the best to perform this kind of conversion. Though I prefer any Object Oriented Language more (like C#, Java etc), I'm open for any programming language that boosts up the conversion. I don't need a GUI frontend for the conversion, running the script/program from console is okay.
Thanks in advance

Comment: C# should be plenty fast if your code is good. Obviously, no one can advise you specifically without knowing what your binary file and database tables look like.

Comment: Please edit your post and explain what type of files you are converting.  What kind of data?  How much?  How many?  Where is it slow? What is slow?  Have you profiled?  Etc...   Then someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of programming language interfaces for SQLite. The language choice **will not be your bottleneck**. SQLite is slow when dealing with inserting large numbers of records.  It doesn't support multiple records per INSERT statement, so the best method is just to wrap the whole thing in an SQL Transaction, running lots of individual INSERT statements.

For this sort of thing, I'd suggest using ruby: [sqlite-ruby gem](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/), but really, whatever language you'd like would work just fine.